# Error while starting slapd

Tags: logs, services, openldap

In my CentOS 6.5 machine I just made a new import with the `slapadd` command to load a new LDIF (from another server).

The `dc`  values are exactly the same and it was working with a previous load. Between two loads I clean the database with `rm -f /var/lib/ldap/*`

But now when I try to start the slapd service with `service slapd start` I get this error:

```
Starting slapd:         [FAILED]
```

I checked if there is an error log somewhere but cannot find it:

- Nothing lokking like `*ldap*` or `*slapd*` in `/var/log` folder
- The `log.000000xxx` files in /var/lib/ldap are looking binaries

Is there any way to find what is the cause why slapd does not start properly?

Comment: If you removed everything from `/var/lib/ldap/`, you'll miss the `DB_CONFIG` file, I guess, which is required so `slapd` (and tools) know with which settings to setup the `bdb`/`hdb` databases.  For further investigation you could try running `slapd -u ldap -g ldap` (or appropriate) from your command line, enabling the `-d` flag (`-d 255` will log very verbosely to `stderr`).

Comment: Thanks for notice me the -d option, it was helpful to see the errors at launch. If you publish this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you removed everything from `/var/lib/ldap/`, you'll be missing the `DB_CONFIG` file, I guess, which is required so slapd (and tools) to know with which settings to setup the `bdb`/`hdb` databases.

Try running `slapd` with debugging enabled to further investigate what is causing `slapd` to refuse starting:

```
# slapd -u ldap -g ldap -d 255
```

This will enable very verbose debug logging to `stderr` (you'll have to adjust the user- and groupname appropriately, of course).